# Alternative API to pyQt signals

Tags: python, pyqt, signals

I am in the process of isolating pyQt calls so that I can implement an alternative view layer (reactJS) for a python application.

Is there alternative lightweight api that I can use as a substitute for QtCore.pyqtSignal() which I have been using quite heavily for gui reactivity?

eg:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject
from PyQt4 import QtCore

__Instance = None

def SpecialSignals(*args, **kw):
    global __Instance
    if __Instance is None:
        __Instance = __SpecialSignals(*args, **kw)
    return __Instance


class __SpecialSignals(QObject):
    ''' special signal object '''
    someToolbar = QtCore.pyqtSignal() 
    smethingActive = QtCore.pyqtSignal() 
    anotherToolbar = QtCore.pyqtSignal() 


    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "isloating PyQt calls"? What does "lightweight" mean? What are you trying to illustrate with the code example?

Comment: @ekjumoro I want to use my code without pyQt, I have isolated all plotting and can replace the plotting with javascript but I still have lots of signal code embedded for example in database related code (signal when table changed for example). I am looking for a signals/events package that is less than a few than a few MB in size that I can use to temporarily replace the ptQt signals until I work out how to best integrate ReactJS with a python backend (push based model update events or pull based events coming from the frontend)

Comment: Requests to recommend programming libraries are off-topic on SO. I suggest you try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ instead.